# Rename multiple files changing the extension and part of the string

Tags: bash, shell, xargs

I have list of `*.new` files in a directory. These file contains `D1` in their names which is to be replaced to `D2` and also have to remove the extension from .new to nothing

```
hello_world_D1_122.txt.new -------> hello_world_D2_122.txt
```

What I tried is

```
ls -slt | grep -iE "*.new$" | awk -F " " '{print $10}' | xargs -I {} mv {} "echo {} | sed -e 's/.D1./.D2./g ; s/.new//g'"
```

This command is not producing the required output. Output of the above command is

```
mv: rename hello_world_D1_122.txt.new to echo hello_world_D1_122.txt.new | sed -e 's/D1/D2/g ; s/.new//g': No such file or directory
```

Comment: What does it do?  Provide sample output of the problem.

Comment: This command shall convert all the file names to the desired ones. Ex: hello_world_D1_122.txt.new -------> hello_world_D2_122.txt

Comment: Deh!  ok.  I meant what does your current command do?

Comment: You shall not see anything on the console but once the command is processed the results can be seen

Comment: my command give me this output .   mv: rename hello_world_D1_122.txt.new to echo hello_world_D1_122.txt.new | sed -e 's/D1/D2/g ; s/.new//g': No such file or directory

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your current attempt contains a large number of problems in addition to the obvious syntax error.

The argument `"echo {} | sed '...'"` is a literal string; there is no way `xargs` could interpret this as a command (though it will of course replace `{}` with the file name inside this string).

In addition, [don't use `ls` in scripts](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs) and if you really have to, using `ls -l` and then throwing away the long format is ... just silly, as well as inefficient, and error-prone (see the link for details).

The obvious and superior way to solve this is without `xargs`:

```
for f in ./*.new; do
    [ -f "$f" ] || continue   # in case the glob matches no files
    d=${f%.new}               # trim off extension
    mv "$f" "${d/.D1./.D2.}"  # replace .D1. with .D2.
done
```

(I imagine you want to replace literal dots, though your regex would match any character except newline followed by `D1` followed by any character except newline.)

If you insist on an `xargs` solution, you can wrap the above script in `bash -c '...'` and pass that to `xargs`:

```
printf '%s\0' ./*.new | xargs -r0 bash -c 'for f; do d=${f%.new}; mv "$f" "${d/.D1./.D2.}"; done' _
```

Comment: There are also a number of questions on this site about how to use the various `rename` commands, some of which can easily do this, which do not yet outnumber the count of atoms in the known universe.

Comment: Looks more or less similar to mine (not claiming plagiarizing though) `++`

Comment: Yeah, just saw your update -- I would delete this if I didn't refer to it from comments to the other anwer.

Answer (score 4):

Why all the round about ways using a bunch of shell tools, you can use the `bash` tool built-ins for this, using parameter-expansion syntax for string manipulation

```
for file in *.new; do 
    [ -f "$file" ] || continue
    temp="${file%*.new}"
    mv -- "${file}" "${temp/D1/D2}"
done
```

The part `"${file%*.new}"` strips of the extension `.new` from the file name and `"${temp/D1/D2}"` replaces `D1` with `D2`

I've no idea why the persistence to use GNU `xargs`, but you can use this un-readable way to achieve that. Using `printf` to list the files with null delimit and use `xargs -0` to read with the null as the delimit character,

```
printf '%s\0' *.new | xargs -0 -r -I {} sh -c 'temp="${0%*.new}"; mv -- "${0}" "${temp/D1/D2}"' {}
```

Comment: `${var/pattern/replacement}` isn't properly portable to `sh`.

Comment: @tripleee: Really? interesting! is it mentioned in the official docs?

Comment: http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_06_02 enumerates the POSIX shell parameter expansions. This string substitution mechanism is not included there.

Answer (score 1):

Using GNU Paralllel it looks like this:

```
parallel mv {} '{=s/D1/D2/;s/.new//=}' ::: *.new
```

If you have crazy filenames:

```
touch "$(printf "Shell  Special\n\n'*$!_D1_txt.new")"
parallel -0 mv {} '{=s/D1/D2/;s/.new//=}' ::: *.new
```